# Unknown error In BungeeCord plugin

Tags: java, intellij-idea, minecraft, bungeecord

I have recently started to learn `Java` and my first BungeeCord plugin is a simple ping command.

(Exra Info)
This is a `BungeeCord plugin` made using `IntelliJ IDEA` - I was following a `videographical` tutorial online and while they were successful - but me not. 
I already trace through the video to assure I have not missed anything from the video that could affect the plugin.

Below(in the code blocks) is the error I received:

**ERROR LOGS**

```
10:10:24 [INFO] Using standard Java JCE cipher.
10:10:24 [INFO] Using standard Java compressor.
10:10:24 [INFO] Enabled BungeeCord version git:BungeeCord-Bootstrap:1.12-SNAPSHOT:b8e6feb:180
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by io.netty.util.internal.ReflectionUtil (file:/C:/Users/alibill96/Pictures/BrontideGD_files/New%20folder/Bungee/BungeeCord(8).jar) to constructor java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of io.netty.util.internal.ReflectionUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
10:10:25 [INFO] Discovered module: ModuleSpec(name=cmd_alert, file=modules\cmd_alert.jar, provider=TravisCiModuleSource())
10:10:25 [INFO] Discovered module: ModuleSpec(name=cmd_find, file=modules\cmd_find.jar, provider=TravisCiModuleSource())
10:10:25 [INFO] Discovered module: ModuleSpec(name=cmd_list, file=modules\cmd_list.jar, provider=TravisCiModuleSource())
10:10:25 [INFO] Discovered module: ModuleSpec(name=cmd_send, file=modules\cmd_send.jar, provider=TravisCiModuleSource())
10:10:25 [INFO] Discovered module: ModuleSpec(name=cmd_server, file=modules\cmd_server.jar, provider=TravisCiModuleSource())
10:10:25 [INFO] Discovered module: ModuleSpec(name=reconnect_yaml, file=modules\reconnect_yaml.jar, provider=TravisCiModuleSource())
10:10:25 [INFO] Loaded plugin AlwaysOnline version 6.1 by Johnnywoof
10:10:25 [INFO] Loaded plugin reconnect_yaml version git:reconnect_yaml:1.12-SNAPSHOT:b8e6feb:180 by SpigotMC
10:10:25 [INFO] Loaded plugin cmd_find version git:cmd_find:1.12-SNAPSHOT:b8e6feb:180 by SpigotMC
10:10:25 [INFO] Loaded plugin cmd_server version git:cmd_server:1.12-SNAPSHOT:b8e6feb:180 by SpigotMC
10:10:25 [INFO] Loaded plugin cmd_alert version git:cmd_alert:1.12-SNAPSHOT:b8e6feb:180 by SpigotMC
10:10:25 [INFO] Loaded plugin cmd_send version git:cmd_send:1.12-SNAPSHOT:b8e6feb:180 by SpigotMC
10:10:25 [INFO] Loaded plugin cmd_list version git:cmd_list:1.12-SNAPSHOT:b8e6feb:180 by SpigotMC
10:10:25 [INFO] Loaded plugin AMCbungeecore version 1.0 by Bitzy_
10:10:25 [SEVERE] Exception in thread "main"
10:10:25 [SEVERE] java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid configuration encountered - this is a configuration error and NOT a bug! Please attempt to fix the error or see https://www.spigotmc.org/ for help.
10:10:25 [SEVERE]     at net.md_5.bungee.conf.YamlConfig.load(YamlConfig.java:69)
10:10:25 [SEVERE]     at net.md_5.bungee.conf.Configuration.load(Configuration.java:67)
10:10:25 [SEVERE]     at net.md_5.bungee.BungeeCord.start(BungeeCord.java:264)
10:10:25 [SEVERE]     at net.md_5.bungee.BungeeCordLauncher.main(BungeeCordLauncher.java:112)
10:10:25 [SEVERE]     at net.md_5.bungee.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:15)
10:10:25 [SEVERE] Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.error.YAMLException: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
10:10:25 [SEVERE]     at org.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.StreamReader.update(StreamReader.java:254)
10:10:25 [SEVERE]     at org.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.StreamReader.peek(StreamReader.java:160)
10:10:25 [SEVERE]     at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.scanPlain(ScannerImpl.java:2003)
10:10:25 [SEVERE]     at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.fetchPlain(ScannerImpl.java:1046)
10:10:25 [SEVERE]     at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.fetchMoreTokens(ScannerImpl.java:401)
10:10:25 [SEVERE]     at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.checkToken(ScannerImpl.java:226)
10:10:25 [SEVERE]     at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl$ParseIndentlessSequenceEntry.produce(ParserImpl.java:531)
10:10:25 [SEVERE]     at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.peekEvent(ParserImpl.java:157)
10:10:25 [SEVERE]     at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.checkEvent(ParserImpl.java:147)
10:10:25 [SEVERE]     at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeSequenceNode(Composer.java:200)
10:10:25 [SEVERE]     at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeNode(Composer.java:152)
10:10:25 [SEVERE]     at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeValueNode(Composer.java:249)
10:10:25 [SEVERE]     at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeMappingChildren(Composer.java:240)
10:10:25 [SEVERE]     at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeMappingNode(Composer.java:228)
10:10:25 [SEVERE]     at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeNode(Composer.java:154)
10:10:25 [SEVERE]     at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeValueNode(Composer.java:249)
10:10:25 [SEVERE]     at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeMappingChildren(Composer.java:240)
10:10:25 [SEVERE]     at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeMappingNode(Composer.java:228)
10:10:25 [SEVERE]     at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeNode(Composer.java:154)
10:10:25 [SEVERE]     at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeDocument(Composer.java:122)
10:10:25 [SEVERE]     at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.getSingleNode(Composer.java:105)
10:10:25 [SEVERE]     at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.getSingleData(BaseConstructor.java:140)
10:10:25 [SEVERE]     at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.loadFromReader(Yaml.java:524)
10:10:25 [SEVERE]     at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.load(Yaml.java:452)
10:10:25 [SEVERE]     at net.md_5.bungee.conf.YamlConfig.load(YamlConfig.java:66)
10:10:25 [SEVERE]     ... 4 more
10:10:25 [SEVERE] Caused by: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
10:10:25 [SEVERE]     at java.base/java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(Unknown Source)
10:10:25 [SEVERE]     at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
10:10:25 [SEVERE]     at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
10:10:25 [SEVERE]     at java.base/java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
10:10:25 [SEVERE]     at org.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.UnicodeReader.read(UnicodeReader.java:125)
10:10:25 [SEVERE]     at org.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.StreamReader.update(StreamReader.java:223)
10:10:25 [SEVERE]     ... 28 more
```

Does anyone know what I've done wrong?

Comment: This is not the website for Minecraft plugin problems. Regardless, you might want to look at your config file for Bungeecord

Comment: Where is the place then

Comment: Your configuration file is not correct. Check syntax and charset.

Comment: @JacobB. [It actually is](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bukkit/info)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably used an invalid character somewhere in one of bungee's configuration files. Try looking through all the configuration options you changed and add single quotes (`' '`) around any strings. If that doesn't help, you could delete all `.yml` files and allow bungee to regenerate them.